# "cross drafts ahoy" meaning

Tags: meaning

In the 4th episode of the 3rd season of Silicon Valley HBO show, the following dialog happens between the landlord and a guy who want to rent a room:

> Guy : Uh, this is not even a room. This is a hallway.
>
> Landlord : Uh, it can't be, because that is a bed, thus, this is a
>   bedroom. Two entrances and exits, **cross drafts ahoy**.

I can't figure out what does the "cross drafts ahoy" stand for. Any ideas?)

Comment: If a room has two entrances (doors) there's likely to be a *(cross-) **draft*** of cold air. In such contexts, ***ahoy*** just means "Beware! - [danger] coming up!".

Comment: Shiver me slumbers.